# Makefile test if variable is not empty

Tags: makefile

In a makefile I'm trying to

- run a shell command and capture the output in a make variable
- do something if the variable is not empty

I've created this simplified makefile to demonstrate my problem. Neither `make a` or `make b` executes the body of the if, I don't understand why not.

```
.PHONY: a b

a:
    $(eval MY_VAR = $(shell echo whatever))
    @echo MY_VAR is $(MY_VAR)
    $(info $(MY_VAR))
ifneq ($(strip $(MY_VAR)),)
    @echo "should be executed"
endif
    @echo done

b:
    $(eval MY_VAR = $(shell echo ''))
    @echo MY_VAR is $(MY_VAR)
    $(info $(MY_VAR))
ifneq ($(strip $(MY_VAR)),)
    @echo "should not be executed"
endif
    @echo done
```

I'm using

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
```

Edit: as pointed out, the vars don't need to be make vars

Comment: There are several problems, and misunderstandings. Your `MY_VAR` is a `make` variable, set it without a `<tab>` to its value, and no need to `$(eval ...)`. `MY_VAR:=$(shell echo whatever)` is enough. No `<tab>` before `$(info ...)` neither, this is `make`

Comment: If you want to do something if not empty, you need to use `$(if $(strip $(MY_VAR)),do if,do else)` in the recipe line

Comment: @Zelnes I only want to set `MY_VAR` when target `a` or `b` is run (the real commands are expensive and there are other targets that don't need it), if I remove the tabs I get syntax errors.

Comment: Ahh, a different form of if, works! Please make an answer so I can accept.

Comment: If you only want these variables to be set/used within the `a` and `b` targets, why make them `make` variables?  Why  not just use shell variables within the recipe?  Trying to use `make` variables here adds a lot of complexity.

Comment: @MadScientist thanks, it doesn't need to be a make var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, due to the time of evaluation, make conditionals (`ifeq`, `ifneq`...) cannot be used in recipes the way you tried. Use shell conditionals, instead, as shown below.

As your `MY_VAR` variable is used only in recipes, is target-dependent and you want it to be computed only when needed, why don't you use shell variables, instead of make variables?

```
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: a b

a:
    MY_VAR=$$(echo 'whatever') && \
    echo '$@: MY_VAR is $$MY_VAR' && \
    if [ -n "$$MY_VAR" ]; then \
      echo '$@: should be executed'; \
    fi && \
    echo '$@: done'

b:
    MY_VAR=$$(echo '') && \
    echo '$@: MY_VAR is $$MY_VAR' && \
    if [ -n "$$MY_VAR" ]; then \
      echo '$@: should not be executed'; \
    fi && \
    echo '$@: done'

$ make a
a: MY_VAR is whatever
a: should be executed
a: done

$ make b
b: MY_VAR is
b: done
```

In case you absolutely need `MY_VAR` to be a target-specific make variable, but want to execute only once (per target) the shell command that produces its value, MadScientist has a [wonderful trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50771834/how-to-get-at-most-once-semantics-in-variable-assignments) that you should probably look at. Applied to your case, it should look like:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.1
...

$ cat Makefile
a: MY_VAR = $(eval a: MY_VAR := $$(shell echo 'whatever'))$(MY_VAR)
b: MY_VAR = $(eval b: MY_VAR := $$(shell echo ''))$(MY_VAR)

a:
    @echo '$@: MY_VAR is $(MY_VAR)' && \
    if [ -n "$(MY_VAR)" ]; then \
      echo '$@: should be executed'; \
    fi && \
    echo '$@: done'

b:
    @echo '$@: MY_VAR is $(MY_VAR)' && \
    if [ -n "$(MY_VAR)" ]; then \
      echo '$@: should not be executed'; \
    fi && \
    echo '$@: done'

$ make a
a: MY_VAR is whatever
a: should be executed
a: done

$ make b
b: MY_VAR is
b: done

$ make b a
b: MY_VAR is
b: done
a: MY_VAR is whatever
a: should be executed
a: done
```

It may look extremely strange but it guarantees that `MY_VAR` is computed if and only if targets `a` or `b` are invoked, and only at most once for each. Have a look at [MadScientist's post](http://make.mad-scientist.net/deferred-simple-variable-expansion/) for detailed explanations. Go, it's brilliant.

Comment: wow, such a good answer. Although I specified it should be a make var, it actually doesn't need to be. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dynamically test the content of `MY_VAR`, you may have to :

```
a:
    $(eval MY_VAR = $(shell echo ''))
    $(if $(strip $(MY_VAR)),echo ok,echo no)
```

`if` evaluation will become `echo ok` if `MY_VAR` is not empty, otherwise it will become `echo no`

Comment: Specifically, the `ifneq` conditionals happen at a different point to the inline `$(if )` conditionals: in parsing the Makefile, not when executing the rule.

Answer (score 1):

The `ifeq` and family of conditionals are evaluated when parsing the Makefile.  If you want a conditional for a Make variable when expanding a rule, you'll want to use the `$(if )` function:

```
.PHONY: a b

a b:
    @$(if $(strip $(MY_VAR)),echo "MY_VAR isn't empty",)
    @echo done

a: MY_VAR =
b: MY_VAR = something
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit left field, but was useful in my case so I guess it's worth a share: pipe the value to `xargs` with the `--no-run-if-empty` option:

```
echo $(POSSIBLY_EMPTY) | xargs --no-run-if-empty echo
```

Note that this will **not** work on OSX. See [How to ignore xargs commands if stdin input is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296710/how-to-ignore-xargs-commands-if-stdin-input-is-empty) for more details on `xargs --no-run-if-empty`