# Variable depending on target

Tags: makefile

Is there a way to force a target-rule to run as part of setting a something in a variable?

For example let's say we have a target and rule:

```
all_mp3s:
    find / -name "*.mp3" > all_mp3s
```

And then a variable:

```
MP3S := $(file < all_mp3s)
```

Is there a way to make sure `all_mp3s` file is getting created before evaluating the `MP3S` variable?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me. Are you looking for the [`shell` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html#Shell-Function)? You could do something like `MP3S := $(shell find / -name "*.mp3")`

Comment: Instead of seeking a convoluted solution to an x-y-problem, what is your *actual* goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple straightforward way to force a rule to be evaluated before a variable gets assigned. There are more complex ways. The following is for GNU make.

Let's first assume that you want to run the (slow) `find` command only if the file `all_mp3s` does not exist, else use its content. You can use GNU make conditionals:

```
ifeq ($(wildcard all_mp3s),all_mp3s)

MP3S := $(shell cat all_mp3s)

else

MP3S := $(shell $(MAKE) all_mp3s ; cat all_mp3s)

endif

all_mp3s:
    find / -name "*.mp3" > $@
```

But I if your Makefile is more complex than this, uses `MP3S` several times, and what you really want is:

- avoid running your super-slow `find` several times,
- run it only if needed (and only once),
- get the result in a file (`all_mp3s`) plus a make variable (`MP3S`),

MadScientist has a [wonderful GNU make trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50771834/how-to-get-at-most-once-semantics-in-variable-assignments) that can be used here:

```
MP3S = $(eval MP3S := $$(shell find / -name "*.mp3"))$(MP3S)

all_mp3s:
    printf '%s\n' '$(MP3S)' > all_mp3s

.PHONY: help clean

help:
    printf 'MP3 finder\n'

clean:
    rm -f all_mp3s
```

If the `MP3S` [recursively expanded make variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors) is expanded because some part of your Makefile is evaluated and needs its value (e.g. if you run `make all_mp3s` while `all_mp3s` does not exist), the find command will be run, its result stored in the variable... and the variable will be turned into a [simply expanded make variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors), which further expansions, if any, will reuse the same, already computed, value.

Else, if your invocation of make (e.g. `make clean`or `make help`) does not need `MP3S` value, the `find` command will not even be run.

The `all_mp3s` file is generated from the value of `MP3S` (instead of the opposite in the other solution).

However, there is another important thing to decide: do you want to declare `all_mp3s` as a phony target:

```
.PHONY: all_mp3s
```

or not?

- If you declare it as phony, the `find` command will be run once and only once each time you invoke `make all_mp3s` (or another goal that depends on `all_mp3s`). But targets depending on `all_mp3s` will always be rebuilt too, which is not necessarily what you want.
- If you don't declare it as phony, and the file exists already, the `find` command will not be run at all (unless the value of `MP3S` is needed elsewhere in your Makefile), and the content of `all_mp3s` will not be updated, which is not necessarily what you want.

As you do not give enough information in your question to decide, it is up to you.